# How to move into the next child in Firebase in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON structure

```
   {
      "Fruits" : {
        "-Kf1-6xbGqxAgWEWkPMO" : {
          "Name" : "Apple",
          "Color" : "Red",
          "Size" : "Large",
        },
         "-Kf1-6xbGqxAgWEWkPMO" : {
          "Name" : "Orange",
          "Color" : "Green",
          "Size" : "Medium",
        },
         "-Kf1-6xbGqxAgWEWkPMO" : {
          "Name" : "Tomato",
          "Color" : "Yellow",
          "Size" : "Small",
        }
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
```

My Model. I retrieve and save it into a dictionary

```
class Fruits {

        var Name: String?
        var color: String?
        var size: String?

        init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){
            if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
                Name = snap["Name"]
                color = snap["Color"]
                size = snap["Size"]
            }
        }

    }
```

In my controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var fruitLabel: UIButton!

        ...
        func changedLabel(){
        if let fruitA = fruits[0].fruitLabel {
                    fruitLabel.text(fruitA, for: .normal)//this changed my label to "Apple"
        }else{
                    fruitLabel.text("err", for: .normal)
            }
        }
      @IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
 //how can i change my label to "Orange"?
    }
```

how can i change my label to "Orange"? How can I implement it in button action? I changed it manually by changing the fruits[1].

Comment: Can you please describe in detail. I am not getting what you are doing.

Comment: @ArpitJain I successfully changed my label to Apple form my code above *question[0].fruitLabel*. Now example if u click the next action button, it will change the fruit label from Apple to Orange as you can see in my JSON structure. How can i do that?

Comment: You really need to edit and explain your question, its quite unclear

Comment: @Dravidian I am really sorry, It is hard for  me especially english is not my native tongue. I edited my question, could you take a look again please.